# Requests library not properly directing HTTP requests through proxies

Tags: python, node.js, proxy, python-requests

I know how to use `requests` very well, yet for some reason I am not succeeding in getting the proxies working.  I am making the following request:

```py
r = requests.get('http://whatismyip.com', proxies={'http': 'http://148.236.5.92:8080'})
```

I get the following:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed b
ecause the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or e
stablished connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Yet, I know the proxy works, because using node:

```js
request.get({uri: 'http://www.whatismyip.com', proxy: 'http://148.236.5.92:8080'},
    function (err, response, body) {var $ = cheerio.load(body); console.log($('#greenip').text());});
```

I get the following (correct) response:

```
148.236.5.92
```

Furthermore, when I try the `requests` request at all differently (say, without writing `http://` in front of the proxy), it just allows the request to go through normally without going through a proxy or returning an error.

What am I doing wrong in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As sigmavirus24 says, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1074), which has been fixed, but hasn't yet been packaged up into a new version and pushed to PyPI.

So, if you need this in a hurry, you can upgrade from the git repo's master.

If you're using `pip`, this is simple. Instead of this:

```
pip install -U requests
```

Do this:

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests
```

If you're not using `pip`, you'll probably have to explicitly `git clone` the repo, then `easy_install .` or `python setup.py` or whatever from your local copy.

Answer (score 2):

It's a known issue: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1074

I'm not sure exactly why it's taking so long to fix though. To answer your question though, you're doing nothing wrong.

Comment: +1. But I believe it has already been fixed, it just hasn't been packaged up into a new version and pushed to PyPI. So, if you `pip install -U git+https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests` instead of just `pip install -U requests` (or the equivalent get-from-git-master-instead-of-PyPI if you don't use `pip`), it should work.

Comment: thanks @abarnert, that worked.  You should add that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @jdotjdot: I've added an answer. But I think it might be better to accept this answer instead of mine, because in the long run (and a pretty short long run, most likely), and the answer will be just "upgrade to the new version", and all the complexities about upgrading from `git` will be irrelevant.

Comment: @abarnet, I was unaware that it was fixed already. I thought 1.1.0 came out recently and this wasn't fixed still. Either way, your answer is correct and fixed it.