# Where did requests's "config" option go?

Tags: python, logging, python-requests

On advice from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348857/requests-library-not-properly-directing-http-requests-through-proxies), I updated `requests` to the most recent version from git to get proxies working.  However, I see that the `config` kwarg is gone, preventing me from logging using `config={'verbose': sys.stderr}`, etc., in my code.

Where did it go?  Is it still built in somewhere where I just can't find it?  It was very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the [changelog](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/HISTORY.rst), configuration was removed outright in 1.0.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029717/how-do-i-disable-log-messages-from-the-requests-library), it appears logging is performed and configured via the standard library `logging` module.